# How to prevent swipe one direction of Lazy Column/Row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For example i have a lazy Column;

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.height(100.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red)) {
        items(20){
            Text(text = "Swipe")
        }
    }
}
```

View;

[image]

I want to swipe only down not up. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `NestedScrollConnection` and consume the upward scroll in there. Something like this:

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            return if (delta < 0) {
                Offset.Zero
            } else {
                Offset(available.x, available.y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just assign it to your `LazyColumn` `modifier`:

```
LazyColumn(Modifier.height(100.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red).nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
        items(20){
            Text(text = "Swipe")
        }
    }
```

Flip the if condition in the `onPreScroll` method if you want to block scroll in the other direction.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your support. I am getting error: Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

Comment: I solved it by Add "-Xjvm-default=compatibility" as freeCompilerArgs.